# Get an idea on how to do a simple math game for iOS with Objective-C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, c

I'm a new coder to IOS & seeking a little help on this game based on math: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kwxffvdgtmxumb4/Math%20Game.jpg

> 1. First, I would like to describe the functions of that game:
>
>    - This is a 2 player based game
>    - 1st user will take an item ("X") from the left side & can place it on any of the block between the 9 blocks marked in the middle of the screen with 4 straight lines.
>    - Then the second player can take an item ("O") from the right side & similarly can place on the block.
>    - 1st & 2nd both player will get several moves.
>    - If any player can match a straight line with same 3 items ("X" or "O"), he wins the game. (Likely Tic-Tac-Toe)
>    - If the game goes to a tie, as you see there are total 10 items (5 X's & 5 0's) & total 9 blocks, the player who have already used his all five items will win the game.
>
> 2.Now I'm wondering how to move a label content ("X" or "0") from left/right side to specific block & work correctly.

Comment: Yes, I checked your answer.
Fortunately, I got many codes of Tic Tac Toe game on the internet. But I'm stacked with my one.
Because, In my described game I have to drag an item to desired place. 
But I didn't get any idea/tutorial on how doing this by this code. @Immi

Comment: So you want to know how to implement Tic Tac Toe. Time to do some googling, methinks.

Answer (score 0):

Source GitHub,

A hacky little implementation of Tic Tac Toe; an exercise in learning the basics of iOS development.

Please check [HERE](https://github.com/rshepherd/TicTacToe). I hope u will get your answer.

Comment: @kmsharif Hi what happen, i provided u an example of tic tac toe. Please let me know what happen

Comment: Yes, I practiced with your example. It's based on basic TicTacToe logic.
But I'm still stuck with the drag & drop as I described in the question-
1) 1st user will take an item ("X") from the left side & can place it on any of the block between the 9 blocks marked in the middle of the screen with 4 straight lines.
2) Then the second player can take an item ("O") from the right side & similarly can place on the block.